# how to do show hide content div with crossbrowser?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, jquery-animate

I am doing some content div show hide using with animate but present it's fixed width working but i want to do without width also it's should cross browser also when shrinking down it have to be work elastic wise when the div show mode.

any suggestions or modifications in code.

jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sureshsummy/xUKRf/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to your fixed width problem:

```
$("#content").animate({
    width: $('body').width() -100
}, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 10
}).toggle();
```

**Edit:**
To animate the hide, put the animation function again in the toggle:

```
$("#content").animate({
    width: $('body').width() -100
}, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 1000
}).toggle({
    width: 100
}, {
    queue: false,
    duration: 1000
});
```

Comment: when it's show mode i tested with shrinking down it's not working properly

Comment: this animating working fine but when it's collapsed please have a look at to shrinking down in browser. what i want id exactly elastic mode when it's open mode

Comment: @yyy i 777: what do you mean by shrinking down, and what exactly is shrinkin down? you have to be much more specific

Comment: when i see in collapsed content it has to fixed in any width browser.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get it responsive you shouldn't use fixed measures(px) for width or padding or margin. Instead, you can use %.

I did some tweaks to your CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/xUKRf/10/

I changed the width, padding and margin of the container and the content div to %